# How to get the first two numbers of a string with python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to be able to get the first two numbers in a string and print the first two numbers, I want to do this using regex, this is currently my code:

```
import re
string = str(input("String: "))
product = re.findall('[a-z].*[a-z]', string)      
print(product[0])
```

I would like an output like this for example:

```
 import re
 string = str(input("String: ")) //Air Max 90 or Air Max 987
 //Logic regex here
 //Output
 Air max 90
 Air Max 98
```

Edit:

To clarify, what I need is to display the string with the first two numbers and exclude all the rest of the number that exists.

I want to be able to display the numbers that are in the string, but only the first two, how can I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show some clear sample inputs along with the output you are expecting.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you want the first two _numbers_ or the first two _digits_? (They are not the same.)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have already edited the question

Comment: These strings you want at the output. Are they the first 2 words or 2 words before the number or the whole string and 2 numbers ?

Comment: Regex is not necessarily the tool you might imagine it to be, because regex doesn't "know" anything about grammar or context.  What are the rules for knowing which words preceding the digits should be captured?  Here, the `or` word is not wanted.  We need rules for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^.*?(?:\b\d{2}(?=\s*\d)|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ra7PnR/2)

By using `(?:\b\d{2}(?=\s*\d)|$)` after `^.*?` we make sure to stop match when we get a word starting with 2 digits that must be followed by another digit after optional spaces or else match till the end.

Comment: Bro, thanks, this function works, but if I have this string `Air Max 90 B` it would display `Air Max 90` it should display `Air Max 90 B` but it shouldn't display `Air Max 90 9` for example

Comment: You mean `Air Max 90 B` should remain *as is* but `Air Max 90 9` should become `Air Max 90`?

Comment: Dude, thank you so much, I literally spent yesterday trying to solve this and came up with similar solutions but it didn't actually solve it, this will solve a big problem for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way is to use `re.search()` since it only looks for the first occurrence

```py
import re

regex_pattern = r"^[^\d]*\d{2}"
test_str = "Air Max 987"

desired_result = None

try:
    desired_result = re.search(regex_pattern, test_str).group()
except AttributeError as e:
    print('No match')
    
print(desired_result)
```

output

```
Air Max 98
```

Regex explanation:

```
/^[^\d]*\d{2}/gm

^ asserts position at start of a line

Match a single character not present in the list below [^\d]

* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

{2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
```

Comment: Your code finds the first two digits, not the first two numbers.

Comment: Oh okay, let me wait for OP clarification then I can edit my answer.

Comment: @Epsi95 This works, but what if I want to display the string?  how do I do?

Comment: Your answer is close to what I want, I'll give it a +1, only one detail is missing, I want that if there aren't two numbers in the string, it shows how far the string goes, for example, I need the string `Air Max 9 something ` is displayed in the same way, or is this string also for example `Air Max 9` is also displayed in the same way

Comment: can you give some examples, I am unable to understand your question

Comment: This string for example `Air Max 1 98` should also be displayed in the same way

Comment: what whill be the output? `Air Max 1`?

Comment: if yes try the regex `^[^\d]*\d{0,2}`

Answer (score 0):

The "best" I can do here is to phrase your requirement as saying match all numbers along with any string coming before them which also happens to start with an uppercase letter (i.e. is some kind of proper noun).  Consider this solution:

```py
string = "Air Max 90 or Air Max 987"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w+)* \d+\b', string)
print(matches)  # ['Air Max 90', 'Air Max 987']
```